# How can I move container lower in the page? Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

If I have a navbar that is hiding part of the container. How can I move the container lower in the page so I can see the whole container please? I tried editing a bit in the CSS but I couldn't fix it.

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id = "nav">        
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_target">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class ="collapse navbar-collapse" id = "collapse_target">
    <h3 class = "navbar-text">Music Cloud</h2>
        <ul class ="navbar-nav" >
            <li class = "nav-item">
                <a class = "nav-link" href = "index1.php">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class = "nav-item">
                <a class = "nav-link" href = "#">List</a>
            </li>
            <li class = "nav-item">
                <a class = "nav-link" href = "register.php">Register</a>
            </li>
            <li class = "nav-item">
                <a class = "nav-link" href = "login.php">Log-in</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </nav>

<div class = "container">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-sm-5">
                <h2>Register an Account</h2>
                <input class = "form-control" type="password" id="password" name = "password"/><br />
                <p>Confirm Password:</p>
                <input class = "form-control" type="password" id="password2" name = "password2"/><br />
                <input type="file" name="image" id="image"><br /><br />
                <input class = "btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You are using fixed-top. which means the nav.  is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used to position the element.

A workaround is setting the margin-top of the container to be slightly higher than the nav height. you can find this in the bootsrap variables.

Comment: Thank you very much I removed fixed-top and it worked!

Comment: Instead of `fixed-top` you can use `sticky-top`. "A sticky element toggles between relative and fixed, depending on the scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place (like position:fixed)."